# Hemisphere "Temperatures" of a 3-Sphere

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

In researching the construction of a 3-sphere, I ran into an insight on Wikipedia that I haven't been able to find in other locations:

"Note that the interiors of the 3-balls are not glued to each other. One way to think of the fourth dimension is as a continuous real-valued function of the 3-dimensional coordinates of the 3-ball, perhaps considered to be "temperature". We take the "temperature" to be zero along the gluing 2-sphere and let one of the 3-balls be "hot" and let the other 3-ball be "cold". The "hot" 3-ball could be thought of as the "upper hemisphere" and the "cold" 3-ball could be thought of as the "lower hemisphere". The temperature is highest/lowest at the centers of the two 3-balls."

Does anyone know of a webpage/chapter that takes a more rigorous approach to defining this continuous real-valued function?

Comment: I don't have any references for you, but it's pretty straightforward. The temperature is the "height" along the 4th axis. What more is there to say?

Comment: Ah, alright, I was reading into the term "temperature" a little oddly. Thanks for the quick clarification.

Comment: Imagine we live in flatland. We can consider two disks, with temp 0 at their boundary circles. Cold disk has temp decreasing to –1 toward its center. Hot disk has temp increasing to +1 at its center. Some bong hits and we learn to visualize temperature promoting it to "height" along the third dimension, and now we "see" the two disks as a 2-sphere. You're describing the same thing, with all the dimensions increased by one.

Comment: Other techniques for "visualizing" a 3-sphere include viewing the fourth coordinate as time, or moving to stereographic projection into $\mathbb{R}^3.$